# PHP force download .png file

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine, download, ftp

Hello and thank you for your time.

I am trying to use the following code to force a download of a .png image that is created from a Unity application I developed onto the users computer.

```
    <?php
    //get the input information
    $stringName = $_POST["stringName"];//name
    $imageString = $_POST["imageString"];//image in string form

    $dataX = base64_decode($imageString);//make the string into the image
    file_put_contents($stringName, $dataX);//save the image on the server
//everything thing above this line works within Unity

    $fileSize = filesize($stringName);//get the file size

    //bunch of headers, comments next to the ones I have an idea about
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: private",false);
    header("Content-Type: imagepng");//gives content type
    header("Content-Length: ".$fileSize);//file size
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$stringName);//download file path
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile( $stringName );
?>
```

I have this but it doesn't pop up with a download confirmation box, or do anything with the provided image.

When running my program in a browser I get ether one of two errors when calling the above script. Since I am hosting the application from dropbox I get "cannot send from https to http", and when I change the address for the php file to https it times out.

So first, is there a way to get the https, and http to allow communication between the two, I would prefer NOT having to host my unity project on the ftp server as I have a few projects set up the same way. Second, will that PHP script work correctly, and if so is there some stuff I can cut out?

Comment: Can you provide additional information about the http/https issue?

Comment: Mixed Content: The page at 'https://URL' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://URL'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Is the error I am getting from the console.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will successfully force download of the file "example.png":

```
<?php

// requested file's name
$file_name = "example.png";

// make sure it's a file before doing anything
if(is_file($file_name))
{
  // required for IE
  if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression')) { ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off'); }

  // get the file mime type using the file extension
  switch(strtolower(substr(strrchr($file_name,'.'),1)))
  {
      case 'pdf': $mime = 'application/pdf'; break;
      case 'zip': $mime = 'application/zip'; break;
      case 'jpeg':
      case 'jpg': $mime = 'image/jpg'; break;
      case 'png': $mime = 'image/png'; break;
      default: $mime = 'application/force-download';
  }
  header('Pragma: public');   // required
  header('Expires: 0');       // no cache
  header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
  header('Cache-Control: private',false);
  header('Content-Type: '.$mime);
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file_name).'"');
  header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
  header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file_name));    // provide file size
  readfile($file_name);       // push it out
}

?>
```